# SQL Server query speed is difference when filtering by different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database with just one table `Logs` that contains columns:

- `Id` (PK Clustered, int, not null),
- `ServiceName` (nvarchar(255), not null) and some other columns like
- `TaskVariant` (nvarchar(1024)),
- `Source` (nvarchar(1024)).

I have created an index `INDEX_SERVICENAME` (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) on the `ServiceName` column and that includes all columns except `Id, ServiceName`.

- Database size around 4 GB.
- Table contains around 3 500 000 rows.
- Table contains around 1 400 000 rows with Source = N'IpJob'.
- Table contains around 2 400 000 rows with TaskVariant = N'Ip'.
- Table contains around 600 000 rows with ServiceName = '1' and TaskVariant = N'Ip'.
- Table contains around 350 000 rows with ServiceName = '1' and Source = N'IpJob'.

Problem:

I want to select all columns from table filtering by `ServiceName` and by `TaskVariant` or by `Source` with paging. My original query is for selecting last 100 items filtering by `Source` is:

```
SELECT TOP (100) 
[Filter1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Filter1].[Date] AS [Date], 
[Filter1].[Data] AS [Data], 
[Filter1].[ServiceName] AS [ServiceName], 
[Filter1].[LogLevel] AS [LogLevel], 
[Filter1].[StackTrace] AS [StackTrace], 
[Filter1].[TaskVariant] AS [TaskVariant], 
[Filter1].[Source] AS [Source], 
[Filter1].[Message] AS [Message]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], [Extent1].[Data] AS [Data], [Extent1].[ServiceName] AS [ServiceName], [Extent1].[LogLevel] AS [LogLevel], [Extent1].[StackTrace] AS [StackTrace], [Extent1].[TaskVariant] AS [TaskVariant], [Extent1].[Source] AS [Source], [Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] DESC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Logs] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (@serviceName = [Extent1].[ServiceName]) AND (@source = [Extent1].[Source])
)  AS [Filter1]
WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Filter1].[Id] DESC
```

This query works very fast ~ 00:00:00 time.

But when I tried to filter by `TaskVariant` query takes ~ 00:02:18 minutes (next query).

```
SELECT TOP (100) 
[Filter1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Filter1].[Date] AS [Date], 
[Filter1].[Data] AS [Data], 
[Filter1].[ServiceName] AS [ServiceName], 
[Filter1].[LogLevel] AS [LogLevel], 
[Filter1].[StackTrace] AS [StackTrace], 
[Filter1].[TaskVariant] AS [TaskVariant], 
[Filter1].[Source] AS [Source], 
[Filter1].[Message] AS [Message]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], [Extent1].[Data] AS [Data], [Extent1].[ServiceName] AS [ServiceName], [Extent1].[LogLevel] AS [LogLevel], [Extent1].[StackTrace] AS [StackTrace], [Extent1].[TaskVariant] AS [TaskVariant], [Extent1].[Source] AS [Source], [Extent1].[Message] AS [Message], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] DESC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Logs] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (@serviceName = [Extent1].[ServiceName]) AND (@taskVariant = [Extent1].[TaskVariant])
)  AS [Filter1]
WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Filter1].[Id] DESC
```

Question: why does the second query execute so much slower and how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Execution Plans[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpflB.png)

Comment: Does your table really not have a clustered index?? Really really bad... it should have on! On `Id` preferably. Many operations are **significantly faster** on a clustered table vs. a heap. See Kim Tripp's excellent blog post [The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) that explains those things in great detail

Comment: Can you show the execution plans for the two queries?

Comment: Sorry, column Id is primary clustered key. I will update question to add this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in execution time you are seeing is primarily due to the fact that the first has an index and second doesn't. As for why it's such a large difference, it's likely the fact that since there's an index, it means that the values are sorted.

Since the values are sorted, you can use very efficient string search algorithms that can make the number of operations when filtering orders of magnitude smaller.

In addition, there's a lot of other characteristics that can affect this. It's possible that the entire index is in memory, while the table data is not, so the filtering in the first query could be done all on memory and never touch the disk, where as the other may not.

Comment: I added the second query. The difference between two queries only in second column (in first case Source, in second - TaskVariant). Both queries uses indexed column ServiceName.

Comment: The same would apply even though you are using the index. The first one it can quickly grab the range of rows and then just stream the results. The second one it can quickly grab the range of keys, but then has to go through each row and filter.

Comment: And how to be with this?

Comment: Now, if i'm right, the query on that column should be really slow when not filtering on the service name but still query on task variant. If it isn't, then it's likely due to statistics. To make them both run fast, you can include the TaskVariant column in the index (you have to make it an included column since that is > 900 bytes)

Comment: Yes you are right, query on that column are also slow without filtering on service name. But all columns was already added as included...

Answer (score 2):

The index works like a hierarchy/tree, with levels corresponding to the columns in it.

So if your index is on `ServiceName, TaskVariant`, you can quickly filter to specific `ServiceName`s because that is the top level in the tree.

But if you try to filter by `TaskVariant`, you now have to read through the entire index: you can't just jump to a specific `TaskVariant` because the same `TaskVariant` will be under different `ServiceName`s.

If you want to filter on TaskVariant, you need *another* index that starts with `TaskVariant`.  NB: don't just create full indices on every column: every index takes up additional space and requires more work on `UPDATE`s and `INSERT`s

Comment: I want to filter on TaskVariant or on Source columns. With filtering on Source query executes fast, but when filtering on TaskVariant - slow. Question why is so big difference in more than 2 min?